Why AT TIME ZONE increases the hours?
In PostgreSQL, I'm trying to convert a hour to local time zone.
My machine has UTC as timezone
show timezone;
UTC

why these queries return different answers?
SELECT '2024-07-01 00:00:00' at time zone 'PST' ;
2024-06-30 16:00:00

SELECT '2024-07-01 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'PST';
2024-07-01 08:00:00+00

thanks

Pakistan Summer time? Those three-letter abbreviations are just that, abbreviations. Not unique identifiers

The two queries don't say the same thing. The first says that '2024-07-01 00:00:00' is PST. The second one says that it's UTC and asks to convert it to PST.

PostgreSQL works with the defacto standard fro timezones, IANA timezone names like America/Chicago. Use these instead of the ambiguous 3/4-letter abbreviations. Guess how many ISTs there are

Note that the first query returns a TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE and the second returns a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. Each time AT TIME ZONE is invoked, the type toggles between the two. As @PanagiotisKanavos mentions, the three letter abbreviations (except for UTC) are not unique: use a time zone name, such as America/New_York. Also be aware that the TIMEZONE setting affects the client's interpretation of text as timestamps and presentation of timestamps as text.

@PanagiotisKanavos. select * from pg_timezone_abbrevs where abbrev = 'PST'; PST    | -08:00:00  | f. Pakistan time would be PK, PAK. The error is that the timestamp is actually in PDT.

set timezone = 'UTC';

SELECT '2024-07-01 00:00:00' at time zone 'UTC';
      timezone       
---------------------
 2024-07-01 00:00:00

SELECT '2024-07-01 00:00:00' at time zone 'PST' ;
      timezone       
---------------------
 2024-06-30 16:00:00

SELECT '2024-07-01 00:00:00' at time zone 'UTC'  AT TIME ZONE 'PST';
        timezone        
------------------------
 2024-07-01 08:00:00+00


In above the AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' is setting time to midnight with no time zone. Then the AT TIME ZONE 'PST' is rotating midnight time to PST and then because the 'local' timezone is UTC, the displayed time is rotated to that for display, note the +00. This moves it 8 hours ahead for the supplied offset. FYI, that offset should be PDT or better yet the timezone name 'America/Los_Angeles'.
